Simple 2-connected outerplanar graphs have a vertex of degree $2$
If $G$ is a simple maximal (or i.e. $2$-connected? are those equivalent?) outerplanar graph, then it contains a vertex of degree $2$. 
This is what we can find by searching in here.
The proof used the fact that the faces in the interior of the outer boundary form a tree.
Now I am looking for a specific proof for this particular setting:
Let $G$ be a simple 2-connected outerplanar graph
a) Show that $G$ has a vertex of degree 2.
b) Consider the dual $G^*$ os $G$, and $v$ the vertex corresponding to the outer face of $G$. Show that $G^*- v$ is a tree.
That is, first show it has a vertex of degree 2 and then use that to show the tree structure of interior faces.

First, note that a large enough maximally outerplanar graph will always be 2-connected, but a cycle on at least four vertices is $2$-connected but not maximally outerplanar, and $K_1$ is maximally outerplanar, but  not $2$-connected.
Let $G$ be a 2-connected outerplanar graph, and consider a fixed drawing of $G$ in the plane. Every face of $G$ is then bounded by a cycle. Let $C$ denote the cycle bounding the outer face of $G$, then $G$ is comprised of $C$ together with potentially some non-crossing chords of $C$. If $G=C$, we are done, so $G$ has at least one chord. Let us say the length $l_e$ of a chord $e$ is the length of a shortest cycle in $C\cup \{e\}$, and denote such a cycle by $C_e$. Consider $e=uv\in E(G)\backslash E(C)$ of minimum length. Since $G$ has no parallel edges, every chord has length at least $3$. Thus, there exists a vertex $w$ on the $uv$-path disjoint from $e$ in $C_{uv}$. Note that $w$ is a vertex of degree $2$, since if $w$ is incident with an edge not in $C_{uv}$, said edge either crosses the edge $e$ or forms a shorter chord, contradicting the minimality of $l_{e}$.
We now prove that $G^*-v$ is a tree, where $v$ is the vertex corresponding to the outer face in $G$. Let $G$ be a counterexample with the fewest chords. Let $w$ be a vertex of degree two in $G$, and let $e$ be a chord in $G$ such that $C_e$ is a face containing $w$. Consider $H = G\backslash e$. By minimality, $H^*-v$ is a tree. But adding $e$ to $H$ corresponds to adding a leaf to $H^*-v$, and adding a leaf to a tree maintains the property of being a tree, a contradiction. We conclude that $G^*-v$ is a tree.

Thank you for the clear answer.
